# How to Validate a CSV file

Tags: java, regex, csv

I want to validate a CSV file.

The condition is that There are 9 columns, separated by commas, like this:

```
something1,some[thi]ng2,some/thing3,so"meth"ing4,somet'hi'ng:5,something6,something7,something 8,something9
```

What is a best way to check if I have those 9 columns in every line when they could by empty like:

```
,,,,,,,,
```

but structure should be OK.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Your example doesn't conform to the CSV syntax: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Comment: but I have to deal with it.

I've tried to write some regexp, but when trying it on http://regexr.com/ nothing worked

Comment: Are you only validating it or are you reading it, what have you tried ? @MauricePerry, well `so"meth"ing4` is a valid cell since this is not enclosed in double quotes, their is no need to escape those. Or I am missing something too ?

Comment: @AxelH a non-escaped field cannot contain DQUOTEs because TEXTDATA doesn't include DQUOTEs (0x22).

Comment: What research have you done? Did you look for CSV parsers in Java?

Comment: @MauricePerry, my bad, point 6 is more restrictive than point 7 about double quote. _"If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped"_ but this "if" is useless since _"Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas should be enclosed in double-quotes"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex that match your input string and the empty one:

```
[^,]*(?:,[^,]*){8}
```

It works only if you test input line by line. See below for a whole file solution.

[See the demo](https://regex101.com/r/DqP5zi/1)

#### Explanation

- `[^,]*` matches any character except the comma 0 or several times.
- `(?:,[^,]*){8}` matches a comma followed by any character but comma 0 or several times, and that 8 times

---

If you test a whole file (multiple lines), you might want to use this expression by specifying `Pattern.MULTILINE` at use:

```
^[^,\r\n]*(?:,[^,\r\n]*){8}$
```

Comment: It's incomplete: the fields can be quoted, in which case they can contain commas.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need

Comment: This also only works reliably, if you read in that file line by line (otherwise `[^;]` may overlap lines) and use a full-match function (otherwise it will match lines with more commas).

Comment: @MauricePerry In a real CSV case, I agree. But it seems that the OP doesn't want to deal with quoted fields.

Comment: @SebastianProske You're right, I've updated my answer. :)